# Getting FileNotFound exception when trying to download images using ParseFile getUrl() method

Tags: android, parse-platform

Android Platform

**My global application config is as follows**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, Application Id, Client key);
        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();       
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }
```

**I saved the file as follows**

```
    ParseObject pIssue = new ParseObject(Constants.STUDENT_CLASS);
    pIssue.put(Constants.STUDENT_TITLE, mTitleView.getText().toString());
    if(mCurrentPhotoPath != null){          
        byte[] imgData = photoHelper.convertFileToByteArray(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        ParseFile pFile = new ParseFile("heya",imgData);
        pIssue.put(Constants.STUDENT_MEDIA_FILES, pFile);           
    }       
    pIssue.saveEventually();
```

**convertFileToByteArray method looks like this**

```
    public byte[] convertFileToByteArray(String filePath) {
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        byteArray = out.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }
```

**I retrieved the image file in a separate thread as follows**

```
f = new File(filename); // this file is valid 
url=parseFile.getUrl(); // this is the url mentioned below
try {
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
    conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    InputStream is=conn.getInputStream(); // code breaks and throws exception here
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
    Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
    os.close();
    conn.disconnect();
    bitmap = decodeFile(f);
    return bitmap;
} catch (Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
   return null;
}
```

The problem is while retrieving I get following exception 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://files.parse.com/e13c8e5c-9234-4160-9d63-b802696f9251/heya

Code breaks at this step - InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();

When I use parseFile.getData(), I get 'Could not decode to bitmap, exception' probably because the data retrieved is not an image.

When I hit the above url from browser I get

```
<Error>
     <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
     <Message>Access Denied</Message>
     <RequestId>.........</RequestId>

     <HostId>
         ...................
     </HostId>
</Error>
```

This error occurs for all files in the table

Please help where am I going wrong .............. :(

Comment: What values are f and url set to?

Comment: f = new File(filename) that I had set above, while url is http://files.parse.com/e13c8e5c-9234-4160-9d63-b802696f9251/heya, i get this from parseFile.getUrl() method

Comment: if you already have valid instance of ParseFile you could look at manual and class=ParseImageView where there is sample code. If you have valid url of the file object, you should be able to get it directly with the HttpUrlConnection class. I know that it works fine with curl.

Comment: Sorry, I have the same doubt and I can´t find the solution. How did you solve this? Please can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The server returns a 403 HTTP error code, which means access is denied. You may need to authenticate first if you haven't done so already.

Specifically for Parse.com, in the [Parse Quickstart](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#android/native/existing) you can find info on how to do the `Parse.initialize` call in the `onCreate()` method of your Activity. Of course, you need your own application id and client id.

Generally, it's good practice to check the HTTP response code, like this:

```
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode >= 300) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "something went wrong. Response code = " + responseCode);
                return null;
            } else {
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                os.close();
                conn.disconnect();
                bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I had initialized my credentials, although I did not mention it in the question, I am able to save and access text data in the parse tables, but for binary data I get the above exception.

Comment: Do you get a 200 HTTP response code when running with your credentials? Does the file get written with the correct content to the location where you want it?

Comment: Still sounds like an authentication issue to me. Looks like there is no public read access set to the images since with a browser or with your app you get a 403. When you access text data successfully, is that in the same activity as when you get the 403?

Comment: yes its the same activity, infact in the same method i get text and I send the parsefile.getUrl() to imageLoader for which I have provided code above, where in conn i get 403